# How do I create a Jetty Server in Eclipse Juno?

Tags: eclipse, jetty

This is what I've done so far:

1. From "**Install New Software**", I chose the site: "http://eclipse-jetty.sourceforge.net/update/"
2. Installed "**Eclipse Jetty Feature**".
3. Restarted Eclipse after the installation.

However, Jetty does not show up in the list of servers in the `New Server` wizard.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? I'm a complete newbie to Java. I'm a C# programmer and I'm learning to use Eclipse and such. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

**UPDATE 1**

Screenshot of **New Server > Download additional server adapters**

[image: Download additional server adapters]

**If I attempt to install the server adapter, I see this error message during the installation:**

[image: Installation Error]

**UPDATE 2**

Screenshot of **Installed software**

[image: Installed software*]

Screenshot of **New Server Wizard**

[image: Define a New Server window]

Screenshot of **Run Configurations**
[image: This is what my Run Configurations window lists:]

Screenshot of **Preferences > Run/Debug > Perspectives**
  [image: Perspectives]

Comment: under Help > Install New Software > what is "already installed" do you have `Eclipse Jetty Feature` ?

Comment: can you please click in `Perspectives` in the `Run Configurations` and see if it's there? Just to check if it's hidden for some reason in the current perspective you are on.

Comment: also in the `New Server Wizard > Downwload additional server adapters` does Jetty show up?

Comment: @AndréRicardo: First Comment: yes. Second Comment: No. Third Comment: Yes

Answer (score 2):

Can you confirm `Eclipse Jetty Feature` is installed?

```
 Help -> Install New Software > what is already installed?
```

[image: Eclipse Installation Details]
Then to run Jetty you can add it in the `Run Configurations` or `Debug Configurations` under `Jetty Webapp`

[image: Debug Configurations Jetty Webapp]

[Quick tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jetty-and-eclipse-integration-0) (you don't need the "Run Jetty Run" plugin)

Comment: My `"Run Configurations"` does not have the option `"Jetty Webapp"`. Please see screenshot in updated question.

Comment: Yes Andre, it is installed (please see updated screenshot in the question).

Comment: IMO use run-jetty-run, the jetty wtp integration is currently unmaintained due to lack of community interest.  We (developers) find it far easier to just write a small main method using embedded jetty for your project which doesn't tie you to a particular editor, or use the jetty-maven-plugin for webapp development.  For editor centric folks we just point at run-jetty-run or the Webby project which is an offshoot of m2eclipse.

Comment: I agree with @jessemcconnell btw, but tried to answer the question.