# Cannot install jetty server adapter for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty

**PROBLEM:** When I try to select a Jetty Server Runtime Environment here

[image]

I don't find it, so I click on *Download Additional Server Adapters*

[image]

But it's not there either.

I have installed the *Eclipse Jetty Feature* as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406342/how-do-i-create-a-jetty-server-in-eclipse-juno)

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jetty 9 WTP plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881020/jetty-9-wtp-plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no officially maintained WTP Server Adapters for Jetty.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13881071/775715

Comment: You are right, that's why I'm using Run-Jetty-Run and Eclipse Jetty 3.8.0, but they don't seem to provide a server adapter for Eclipse. So I guess the answer to my question is that it's not possible to have a jetty 9 server adapter in Eclipse.

Comment: Run-Jetty-Run does not provide a WTP Server Adapter in eclipse, never has.  Its a different approach than the antiquated WTP mechanisms.  There are now several dozens of ways to execute Jetty on your project in eclipse, all better than the old school WTP approach.